# ill formatted url returns 500 internal server error what could be the causes?

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

I have an spring boot application which takes in http request and has service interceptor with pre handle method. It is deployed on a tomcat server. If I pass an ill formatted url, it is not hitting the url. I am getting 500 internal server error even before hitting the pre handle method in interceptor what could be the cause?

I tried adding logs in pre handle method of interceptor but I am getting the 500 internal error even before it hits pre handle, is there something that tomcat is doing before the url hits pre handle?

Comment: We would need logs and error messages (please paste these correctly formatted in your question) to start helping

Comment: {
    "timestamp": "2023-07-11T06:11:29.446+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "path": "/authentication//signin"
}
This is the error that I am getting, I am not getting any error logs in console or tomcat server

Comment: Please don't add additional information in the comments as that is totally unreadable. Check your logs as a 500 is tupically the result of an error, there should be a stacktrace some where. If not enable debug logging and try again.